# Interpolating a polynomial of degree $n-1$ given 3 points via Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I know that for any sequences $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n,\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$, there exists $p(x) \in \mathbb R_{n-1}[x]$ where $p(x_i) = y_i$.

I'm given 3 points: $(1, 7), (2, 13), (3, 23)$, and I need to find what $p(x)$ is.

I wrote the polynomial expression as a linear system and got to the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&\cdots & 1 \\
1 &2 &\cdots &2^{n-1}\\
1 & 3 & \cdots & 3^{n-1}\\
\vdots &\vdots &&\vdots\\
1 & x^n &\cdots&x_n^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_3\\ \vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}7\\13\\23\\ \vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}$$

Next, I try to express the solution using Cramer's rule. Already I get the feeling that I have  free variables. I know that the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix that I need to use for Cramer's rule is equal to $|V| = \prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i)$, what I don't know is the determinant of $|V_i|$ — the matrix with the solution in place of column $i$.

How do I proceed? I suppose I can just set everything else to zero and find a 2nd degree polynomial, but I get the feeling a general solution is required here.

Comment: This problem is sufficiently small enough such that you don't really need the Vandermonde determinant... Are you aware of a way to write out the interpolation explicitly?

Comment: @Vasting Only other way I know is by Gaussian elimination, although the guide for solving this explicitly suggests that you use Cramer's rule for this, for which I don't see any way not to use the Vandermonde determinant.